# HUE and Job Scheduler installation for HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue, autosys

I have two separate question regarding the installation of following:
1) I want to install HUE. But the issue here is that I have to hop between servers to access my production node. e.g Login to server A in putty --> ssh into server B --> ssh into server C and this C is my edgenode. This process was done to have security. I have no knowledge of Hadoop Administration, so how do I go about HUE installation here; what are the requirements and configuration needed? How do I access HUE from a portal to access hdfs via impala?

2) I want to install a job scheduler for cloudera distribution. I have worked on CA7 scheduling earlier. Currently in my project we are using CRON to schedule our jobs. But CRON does not have the required features i am looking for like job monitoring, job failure notificaton etc... I was thinking of installing Autosys job scheduler but thats just a thought as I have not worked on that either. Please suggest which is the best and easy scheduler to work with and its installation with similar issue as I have in point 1 above

Comment: Cloudera uses Oozie for job scheduling